# Detect cell entries in MATLAB Table

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a Matlab table (the new 'Table' class), let's call it `A`:

```
A=table([1;2;3],{'A';'B';'C'})
```

As you can see, some of the columns are double, some are cell.

I'm trying to figure out which ones are cells.

For some reason, there is no `A.Properties.class` I can use, and I can't seem to call `iscell` on it.

What's the "Matlab" way of doing this? Do I have to loop through each column of the table to figure out its class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach -

```
out = cellfun(@(x) iscell(getfield(A,x)),A.Properties.VariableNames)
```

Or, a better way would be to access the fields(variables) dynamically like so -

```
out = cellfun(@(x) iscell(A.(x)), A.Properties.VariableNames)
```

Sample runs:

Run #1 -

```
A=table([1;2;3],{4;5;6})
A = 
    Var1    Var2
    ____    ____
    1       [4] 
    2       [5] 
    3       [6] 
out =
     0     1
```

Run #2 -

```
>> A=table([1;2;3],{'A';'B';'C'})
A = 
    Var1    Var2
    ____    ____
    1       'A' 
    2       'B' 
    3       'C' 
out =
     0     1
```

Run #3 -

```
>> A=table([1;2;3],{4;5;6},{[99];'a';'b'},{'m';'n';'p'})
A = 
    Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4
    ____    ____    ____    ____
    1       [4]     [99]    'm' 
    2       [5]     'a'     'n' 
    3       [6]     'b'     'p' 
>> out
out =
     0     1     1     1
```

Comment: Isn't the whole of the 2nd column a 3x1 cell? It just so happens one of the elements of the 3x1 cell is a double. Is the OP's question about identifying which columns are cells?

Comment: What about the test case of A=table([1;2;3],{4;5;6})

Comment: @hiandbaii Ah you are right, that must be considered too!

Comment: Yep. This is exactly what I was looking for. Genius.

Answer (score 0):

You could test with `iscell(A.Var2)` if the second variable is of type cell. More generally, you could reference columns by their index:

```
for k = 1 : width(A)
    disp(iscell(A.(k)))
end
```